# Symfony command doesn't work because it renders a template

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, twig, symfony-2.8

I have generated the command using the Symfonies

```
php app/console generate:command
```

And it generated this command with added

```
class AppTriggerBuildCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('trigger')
            ->setDescription('...')
            ->addArgument('argument', InputArgument::OPTIONAL, 'Argument description')
            ->addOption('option', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Option description')
        ;
    }

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $argument = $input->getArgument('argument');
    if($argument == 'build'){
        $content = $this->pageAction('en', 'home');
        $this->storeContentElementsAction('en', 'home', $content);
    }

    $output->writeln('You are outside build.');
}


public function pageAction($language, $page) {
    $akeneo = $this->getContainer()
        ->get("pimc.akeneo_cms.backend_connector");

    $contentElements = $akeneo->getContentElementList($page);
    $contentElements = $this->sort($contentElements);
    $content = $this->getContainer()->get('templating')->renderResponse(
        'AppBundle::page.html.twig',
        ["contentElements" => $contentElements, "language" => $language]);

    return $content;

}

private function sort($contentElements) {
    ksort($contentElements);
    return $contentElements;
}

/**
 * @param $language
 * @param $page
 */
public function storeContentElementsAction($language, $page, \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $content) {

    $staticalContent = new StaticContent();
    $staticalContent->setData($content->getContent());
    $staticalContent->setBuild(1);
    $staticalContent->setName("/".$language."/".$page.".html");

    $doctrine = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine');
    $em = $doctrine->getManager();
    $em->persist($staticalContent);
    $em->flush();
}
```

}

StaticContent is an entity.

But when I call this command into the command line I have an unusual error which I can't resolve. php app/console trigger build Symfony gives me this error line. 
[image]

Could someone help me so that this command works for me ?

Comment: Change renderResponse to render.  That will get you past this particular error.  Probably have more.

Comment: Hmm, all right. I have changed it from renderResponse to render, but I still have the same exact error. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manipulating a [HTTP Response](https://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) in `pageAction` method, I think you are using the wrong method from twig.

You seem to want store the html returned  into your database as a html string.

*As Cerad pointed in comments* for that you just have to call `$content = $this->getContainer()->get('templating')->render($template, []);`

Now `$content` is your rendered html string.

PS: Reread your code when you copy/paste from another 'context' :D

Comment: Yes, I want to store html string to my database. I have tried to change it from renderResponse to render, but still getting the same error ?!

Comment: Can you try to replace `get('templating')` by `get('twig')` please and run your command with the `-vvv` output. Link the stacktrace to your question to determine in which vendor class your code is going

Comment: Didn't know about the -vvv. Thanks for that Mcsky. 
So I have figured out what was this error all about. 

But it came up with the different error. It expects an instance of Response and I gave to it just the string $content. 

This is the exact error: Type error: Argument 3 passed to AppBundle\Command\AppTriggerBuildCommand::storeContentElementsAction() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, string given, called in /var/  
  www/html/iclei/src/AppBundle/Command/AppTriggerBuildCommand.php on line 30

Comment: Replace `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response $content` by `$htmlStringContent` in `storeContentElementsAction's` prototype and that will be ok :)

Comment: This is a joke. Right ? I don't quite understand. I need a proper reponse from class Response.

Comment: You don't need the HTTP Response class to store html into database. This class don't do anything on the html actually ... What don't you understand ? `$content` isn't anymore an HTTP Response, the error come from here